# ngf-pattern not working for ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, csv, filter, ng-file-upload

I am trying to limit the file type to CSV in the `ng-file-upload` component but it isn't working - it still accepts all files.

I have tried both `ngf-pattern="'*.csv'"` and `ngf-pattern="*.csv"`.

Code:

```
   <button class="btn btn-info" type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
                        ngf-pattern="'*.csv'" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> {{'main.users.import.button' |translate}} </button>
```

Dependency:

```
  "ng-file-upload": "~10.0.2",
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to add the `accept` attribute too and remove the `*`:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" 
type="file" 
ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" 
ngf-pattern="'.csv'" 
accept=".csv" 
ngf-max-height="1000" 
ngf-max-size="1MB">
```

EDIT: accept without single quotes

Comment: how to add multiple filters?

Comment: like this - ngf-pattern="'.csv','.pdf'" accept=".csv,.pdf".

Answer (score 3):

```
<button id="select_resume_btn" class="btn btn-default" type="file" 
        ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" 
        ngf-pattern="'.docx,.pdf'" 
        accept=".docx,.pdf" 
        ngf-max-size="5MB">Select Resume</button>
```

This worked for me !! Thanks @Michelem